# docker swarm + traefik, client ip?

Tags: networking, containers, docker-swarm, traefik

I have a docker-swarm with traefik setup to  route dns requests to containers. everything works  flawlessly until i  hit a roadblock  with ip. so i want to do ip detection on who ever calls one of my endpoints, the request gets into traefik which redirects to the proper container. The issue  i  currently face  is that the ip  is internal: 10.255.0.2.

I read that there is a way of doing it if we set traefik as mode: host. but i have containers spread across nodes  and mode host limits traefik to only one node at a time.

Has anyone been able to solve this in anyway, and have traefik forward ip's to containers across nodes?

Answer (score 3):

We had to solve the issue of identifying client IPs for our production deployment of Docker Swarm at https://www.newsnow.co.uk/.

To solve it, we created: https://github.com/newsnowlabs/docker-ingress-routing-daemon, a daemon that modifies the ingress mesh network routing to expose true client IPs to service containers.

Please check it out.